# Create a booting external harddrive without formatting it

Tags: boot, grub

Ok so here's my situation:
I have an external hard drive, but my pc recognizes it as a normal HDD (not USB). So I have three partitions, one for data storage, filled with (alot of) data, one with a bootable Kali-Linux installation, and one empty partition which I want to install Hiren's boot cd on. I have tried searching all kinds of methods but all of them apply for USB-ish HDDs. I have seen "rufus" but it says it will format the WHOLE drive and I want only one partition. Help? (PS. my E.HDD is a Transcend storejet a58263)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always format individual partitions with `mkfs.whatever`. However, that's not even what you need. What's required to boot from it is a bootloader, which is separate from all partition (the first tiny chunck of hard drive, called MBR - master boot record). There are more modern systems (GPT) but that's not the question here. What you need is to chroot into your linux installation and install the boot sector (grubinstall for grub, but I don't know what you want - syslinux maybe?). It's nice to make the partition bootable (with cfdisk or similar), but I don't think it matters if you have a bootloader.

Then it's just the matter of your BIOS/EFI on your machine to recognize it at all. It's taken long for BIOS to even know what usb is, so there's a chance it can't find it.

You can also dd your image (bootable "cd" like you said) to the partition, something like

```
dd if=/path/to/your/iso of=/dev/sdb3
```

with maybe definitions of block sizes and so on. This simply overwrites that partition with the image (filesystem type, size,... is from iso now). However, it is true that this is usually not done for a partition, but entire hard drive so it may not work. It's probably best to have a proper installation on that partition and then a bootloader that starts it up.

Answer (score 1):

Kali-Linux is based on Debian, so will likely have `GRUB2` as its bootloader. If the system is bootable, then it will be installed on your drive already. All you should have to do is have it recognise your boot cd partition.

First of you will need to find out the device file of your partition, `parted -l` should list all partitions/sizes etc. You can then copy the boot CD to your partition using `dd`. Eg if the target partition is `/dev/sdb2` and your boot cd is in the cd drive, you would do:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sr0 of=/dev/sdb2
```

If you have an ISO file, you can use that as per [orion's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118574/48083).

Once you have that, all you should have to do is run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

from inside Kali-Linux and it should hopefully recognise the new bootable partition and add it to your boot menu.

#### Edit

`update-grub` may not work directly depending on how your system is configured, if so please add its output to the question so we can make further suggestions.